# Expert Opinion Query is it possible

Tags: mysql

i have a table named `students` which have student details `id,mark,name`

i want to get `no of students` , `no of students passed` (Marks is available), `no of students failed`

mark below 50 failed , above passed

is it possible to get `3 counts in a single query` **`without`** using `subquery,join or union`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) TotalStudents,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Mark >= 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalPassed,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Mark < 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalFailed
FROM    students
```

Comment: @astander will it work without using group by , i mean count(*)?

Comment: @Harish, Yes, it will as you are not actually grouping by anything.

Comment: i got an error #1140 - Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

Comment: You wish to retrieve this result accross the entire table, correct?

Comment: i don't get u pls , can you elaborate

Comment: Do you wish to group this by any column?

Comment: but mysql is showing error when i try to execute this query that one i posted in comment

Comment: Are yuo using the query as provided, or is this a watered down version of the complete query? Is there more to your actual query?

Comment: no nothing i'm using the query as such do you get result for the same thing?

Comment: thanks boss! i got that correct ! was a mistake in my query! got it right!

Comment: OK, thought I was going nutz there **X-)**

Comment: can i ask one question? how does this work count(*) and switch case parllelly? because count is supposed to be a group function?

Comment: The COUNT and SUM are group functions. COUNT(*) will count all the rows in the table, where as the SUM will add all rows where the case is equal to 1. As you can see the SUM would be the same as COUNT all rows where the MARK is greater or equal to 50. the case stament produces the 1 or 0 based on the mark entry in the row, and then we just sum them together.

Comment: thanks a lot if there was a provision for favorite users i would have added you!